# I try upload reels video by API but failed to initiate video upload

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Error:
Failed to initiate video upload. Status code: 403

Response content: b'{"error":{"message":"(#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this target","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AnjF6t8q7LwHZ7QkOWSg8_O"}}'

Failed to initiate video upload.

My code :

```py
import requests
import os

title = "Title of the video"
description = title



mp4_path = r"C:\Users\Mrr K\Desktop\Reels API\A.mp4"
files = {'source': open(mp4_path, 'rb')}
file_size = os.path.getsize(mp4_path)
print("File Size is :", file_size, "bytes")

# Step 1: Initiate video upload process
def initialize_video_upload():
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{page_id}/video_reels"
    payload = {
        'upload_phase': 'start',
        'access_token': access_token
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Failed to initiate video upload. Status code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response content:", response.content)
        return None, None
    response_data = response.json()
    video_id = response_data.get("video_id")
    upload_url = response_data.get("upload_url")
    return video_id, upload_url


# Step 2: Upload video content
def upload_video_content(upload_url, video_file_path):
    files = {'video_file': open(video_file_path, 'rb')}
    response = requests.post(upload_url, files=files)
    return response

# Step 3: Publish the video
def publish_video(video_id, description=''):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{page_id}/video_reels"
    payload = {
        'access_token': access_token,
        'upload_phase': 'finish',
        'video_id': video_id,
        'video_state': 'PUBLISHED',
        'description': description
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    return response.json()

# Step 4: Execute the steps
video_id, upload_url = initialize_video_upload()
if video_id and upload_url:
    upload_response = upload_video_content(upload_url, video_file_path)
    if upload_response.ok:
        publish_response = publish_video(video_id, description="Your Video Description")
        print("Publish Response:", publish_response)
    else:
        print("Failed to upload video content.")
else:
    print("Failed to initiate video upload.")
```

Comment: Your token doesn't have the proper authorization.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)